# In C++, how would one unit test a method that must throw an exception when a private array no longer has "space"?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am implementing an ECS system with a data-oriented design, and with a TDD methodology using Catch 2. I have the following class declaration snippet for an `EntityManager`:

```c
using Entity = std::uint16_t;
using Signature = std::bitset<MAX_NUM_COMPONENTS>;

const std::uint16_t MAX_NUM_ENTITIES = 10000;

class EntityManager
{
public:
  ...
  Entity createEntity();
  ...
private:
  Signature entities[MAX_NUM_ENTITIES];
  ...
}
```

The purpose of `EntityManager::createEntity()` is to simply return an `Entity` (which we will refer to as `e`), and set `entities[e]` to some value. However, the method must throw an exception when the number of entities that exists are more than `MAX_NUM_ENTITIES`.

I would like to unit test the aforementioned method. But, I am unsure how to do so. An idea I have is to fill up the entire `entities` array by calling `createEntity()` `MAX_NUM_ENTITIES + 1` times in my test to trigger an exception. However, I have a feeling that it is not the best way to do it, and may even result in a slow test run. Another idea, but similar to the previous one, is to somehow mock `entities` so that it would have a small size. We will then call `createEntity()` multiple times until an exception is raised just like the previous idea.

What approach would you recommend?

Comment: I would call the test in a `try/catch` and put an explicit failure after the call within the `try` block.  The catch can either test the content of the exception or simply it's presence is the pass case.  That's what languages like Java and C# did before they had lambdas or annotations.  Works well.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch, thanks for that suggestion. But, the method should only throw an exception when it has been called more than 10,000 (actually `MAX_NUM_ENTITIES`, but we'll use its actual value instead for simplicity) times (without any prior entity deletions). Would it be wise to call the method inside the `try/catch` block 10,001 times just for the method to throw an exception? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I'd consider changing MAX_NUM_ENTITIES from a const to a constructor parameter, perhaps with a default value.  For your unit test pass a tiny number.

Comment: How regularly is `createEntity()` expected to change? If the answer is never or hardly ever, consider manual testing. For a stable piece of code an automated test that runs all the time doesn’t provide a lot of value, especially if the test is expensive (in runtime or increased test implementation complexity because of a mock).

Comment: We had a similar problem in our company. We couldnt (didnt want to) move MAX_NUM_ENTITIES to a constructor argument, because then it would be fixed at runtime and not at compile time. Our solution was to move it to a template parameter and add a typedef for the original size: `using DefaultEntityManager = EntityManager<10000>`. This way, the unit tests could use `EntityManager<10>`. Would this work in your case?

Comment: @pschill, your solution seems to be a viable one for my case. Thanks! It would require making `MAX_NUM_ENTITIES` a part of `EntityManager` though. But, I suppose that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: It doesn't make `MAX_NUM_ENTITIES` a *part* of `EntityManager`. It makes it a *parameter* of

Comment: This is just the usual area of conflict between testability and simplicity. If you want to keep the class simple and not expose its private parts, then forget about the unit test and test the behaviour at a higher level (i.e. create a realistic situation which will result in too many entities being created and see if the error handling behaves correctly). You will ultimately have to decide if the benefits of unit-testing this class are worth the additional complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how would one unit test a method that must throw an exception when a private array no longer has “space”?

Reverse the question: how would you design a method that would support testing it?

You'd probably arrange things so that your test could control the size of the buffer, so that you can set it to something simple to test, like 1 or 2.  You might also have methods that allow your test to inspect what is going on.

Replacing "designs that are hard to test" with "designs that are easy to test" is an important motivator for [tdd](/questions/tagged/tdd).